# Un-delete count off

Tags: support, 10k-tools, vote-to-undelete

In the 10k tools on Meta, the posts that show having undelete votes have a count showing that is off by 1.  Some of these have no undelete votes showing on the post, so it's not a caching issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you are seeing here.

For the questions that have higher shown on the question than shown in the tools, this is because you're only looking at a time-based filter in the tools. The one with 2 undelete votes, if you look at the 30 day view it shows 3 undelete votes. Undelete votes age away much slower than other votes, if at all.

For the questions that are reported as having 1 undelete vote on the tools, but don't show any on the question, this is because both of them have been undeleted successfully, and were simply re-deleted afterwards. Like close votes, solidified undeletion/deletion votes retain their count even after the choice has been reversed.

Comment: The first paragraph is the answer, but in the second case, I would see three undelete votes (usually).  I've seen that phenomenon before.  It looks like @gnostradamus has the (now deleted) answer to that.

Comment: @Lance Did you check to see if maybe 3 people did actually undelete it, and it just got deleted again afterwards? Because that's the community expansion of that second paragraph.

Comment: Look [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67934/revisions) (10k only) to see why 1 undelete vote shows for one of the posts listed under the 10k tools, even though there are none on the post.