# Do delete/undelete votes age away?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, vote-to-undelete

This doesn't seem to be specificed in the docs and the FAQ.

I see this suggested in [Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285889/lets-plan-the-second-iteration-of-the-stack-exchange-quality-project/285911#285911) (10.2016) and mentioned as an existing feature (!) in [Un-delete count off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67968/un-delete-count-off/67970#67970) (10.2010).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [How Does Deleting Work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/300411) under "How do votes to delete work?":

> Votes to delete or undelete never expire.

This matches my experience; I cast a delete vote in January 2016 on a particular post, and the timeline of that post shows that no additional delete votes have been cast, and that mine has not expired.

Comment: Thanks. I was searching the page for "age" (since it's the official term for the mechanic) so I missed that.